# C# string and sql injection

Tags: sql, entity-framework, sql-injection

I want to protect the DB from SQL Injection attacks, and I have noticed that post http://www.dascode.net/post/2009/11/01/An-example-of-how-to-check-for-SQL-Injections.aspx which can be useful.

Here's scenario (I'm using Entity Framework)

1) user want to add e.g. a comment like "I want to select a book, then open it and get a char".

code snippet (an example):

```
string commVal = "lorem";

using(DB ctx = new DB())
{
   Comment c = new Comment { Value = commVal };
   ctx.Comment.Add(c);
   ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

As you can see it's not a SQL Injection but that string contains unwanted words - `select`, `open`, `char`. So, the only way for prevention from the SQL Injection is to add a quotation marks around that unwanted words ?

Comment: How are you constructing your query? Post some code - i suspect you're already using parametrized sql, in which case this won't be a problem. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716760(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The **only reliable** way to avoid SQL injection is to use **parametrized queries**. Don't even start trying to do a "request cleansing" yourself - you'll **always** miss something.... just use parametrized queries and your troubles go away !

Comment: This horse has been dead for a long, long time: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Comment: Long before Jeff Attwood wrote this article - ADO 1.0 had parameters in 1996

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, and the original article doesn't work at all. The easiest and cheapest way to avoid SQL injection attacks is to used parameterized queries, and EF (and almost all ORMs) does just that.

A parameterized query is a query where all external values are replaced by (strongly-typed) parameters. The parameter values are passed out-of-band so there is no way that SQL Injection can occur.

There are multiple added benefits when using parameterized queries:

- You avoid internationalization errors with ASCII, decimal separators, date formats, because the values are passed as their original types.
- Network traffic is reduced because the native representations are invariably smaller than their text equivalents.
- The resulting queries result in much faster system performance, because SQL Server only has to parse a parameterized query the first time it is sent. Subsequent executions use the original execution plan.

So, the original article is wide open to injection attacks while EF is safe.